# How can I delegate to the __add__ method of a superclass?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, delegation

Say I have this class:

```
class MyString(str):
    def someExtraMethod(self):
        pass
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
a = MyString("Hello ")
b = MyString("World")
(a + b).someExtraMethod()
("a" + b).someExtraMethod()
(a + "b").someExtraMethod()
```

1. Running as is:

   ```
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'someExtraMethod'
   ```
2. Obviously that doesn't work. So I add this:

   ```
   def __add__(self, other):
       return MyString(super(MyString, self) + other)
   def __radd__(self, other):
       return MyString(other + super(MyString, self))
   ```

   ```
   TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'super' objects
   ```
3. Hmmm, ok. `super` doesn't appear to respect operator overloading. Perhaps:

   ```
   def __add__(self, other):
       return MyString(super(MyString, self).__add__(other))
   def __radd__(self, other):
       return MyString(super(MyString, self).__radd__(other))
   ```

   ```
   AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__radd__'
   ```

Still no luck. What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I usually use the `super(MyClass, self).__method__(other)` syntax, in your case this does not work because `str` does not provide `__radd__`. But you can convert the instance of your class into a string using `str`.

To who said that its version 3 works: it does not:

```
>>> class MyString(str):
...     def __add__(self, other):
...             print 'called'
...             return MyString(super(MyString, self).__add__(other))
... 
>>> 'test' + MyString('test')
'testtest'
>>> ('test' + MyString('test')).__class__
<type 'str'>
```

And if you implement `__radd__` you get an `AttributeError`(see the note below).

Anyway, I'd avoid using built-ins as base type. As you can see some details may be tricky, and also you must redefine *all* the operations that they support, otherwise the object will become an instance of the built-in and not an instance of your class.
I think in most cases it's easier to use delegation instead of inheritance.

Also, if you simply want to add a single method, then you may try to use a function on plain strings instead.

---

I add here a bit of explanation about why `str` does not provide `__radd__` and what's going on when python executes a `BINARY_ADD` opcode(the one that does the `+`).

The abscence of `str.__radd__` is due to the fact that string objects implements the concatenation operator of sequences and not the numeric addition operation. The same is true for the other sequences such as `list` or `tuple`. These are the same at "Python level" but actually have two different "slots" in the C structures.

The numeric `+` operator, which in python is defined by two different methods(`__add__` and `__radd__`) is actually a single C function that is called with swapped arguments to simulate a call to `__radd__`.

Now, you could think that implementing only `MyString.__add__` would fix your problem, since `str` does not implement `__radd__`, but that's not true:

```
>>> class MyString(str):
...     def __add__(self, s):
...             print '__add__'
...             return MyString(str(self) + s)
... 
>>> 'test' + MyString('test')
'testtest'
```

As you can see `MyString.__add__` is not called, but if we swap arguments:

```
>>> MyString('test') + 'test'
__add__
'testtest'
```

It is called, so what's happening?

The answer is in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=order%20execution#coercion-rules) which states that:

> For objects `x` and `y`, first `x.__op__(y)` is tried. If this is not
>   implemented or returns `NotImplemented`, `y.__rop__(x)` is tried. If this
>   is also not implemented or returns `NotImplemented`, a `TypeError`
>   exception is raised. But see the following exception:
>
> Exception to the previous item: if the left operand is an instance of
>   a built-in type or a new-style class, and the right operand is an
>   instance of a proper subclass of that type or class and overrides the
>   base’s `__rop__()` method, the right operand’s `__rop__()` method is tried
>   before the left operand’s `__op__()` method.
>
> This is done so that a subclass can completely override binary
>   operators. Otherwise, the left operand’s `__op__()` method would always
>   accept the right operand: when an instance of a given class is
>   expected, an instance of a subclass of that class is always
>   acceptable.

Which means you must implement *all* the methods of `str` *and* the `__r*__` methods, otherwise you'll still have problems with argument order.

Answer (score 2):

May be:

```
class MyString(str):
  def m(self):
    print(self)

  def __add__(self, other):
    return MyString(str(self) + other)

  def __radd__(self, other):
    return MyString(other + str(self))    

a = MyString("Hello ")
b = MyString("World")
(a + b).m()
```

Update: you last version with `super` works for me